# Center a button in a Linear layout

Tags: xml, android, layout

I am using a linear layout to display a pretty light initial screen.  It has 1 button that is supposed to centre in the screen both horizontally and vertically.  However no matter what I try to do the button will top align centre.  I have included the XML below, can some one point me in the right direction?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnFindMe" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/findme"></ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What fixed it for me in a LinearLayout with horizontal alignment was to set `layout_width` to "wrap_content". Subsequently the `layout_gravity` did what it was supposed to do !

Comment: If you strictly need to use LinearLayout, I think this should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051472/how-to-center-the-content-inside-a-linear-layout

Answer (score 392, accepted):

If you want to center an item in the middle of the screen don't use a `LinearLayout` as these are meant for displaying a number of items in a row.

Use a [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) instead.

So replace:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

for the relevant `RelativeLayout` option:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

So your layout file will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnFindMe" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/findme"></ImageButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There are instances where you need to use a LinearLayout and center content. This should not be the accepted answer. It would be better to suggest to use a RelativeLayout if possible, and if not _how_ to center in a LinearLayout.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that a RelativeLayout is much more runtime intensive due to the way they have to have their dimensions measured, whereas a LinearLayout is super straightforward and much more efficient.

Answer (score 466):

Center using a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFindMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/findme" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: LinearLayout is simpler and lighter-weight compared to a RelativeLayout, should be a little faster.

Comment: I was using layout_gravity instead of gravity. changing to android:gravity="center" fixed this for me. rookie mistake.

Comment: @ackushiw was also my problem!

Comment: At least for me android:gravity="center" LinearLayout attribute did the trick. Thank you bro!

Answer (score 47):

Have you tried defining `android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"` inside the layout and setting `android:layout_weight="1"` in the image?

Comment: I like this option which lets me keep mi LinearLayout ! (I didn't have to set `android:weight="1"` in the button to center it though.)

Comment: android:gravity doesn't work for me in a horizontal LinearLayout, but android:layout_gravity does.

Answer (score 37):

A commonly-used method that works with linear layout is to set a property on the image button

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

You can choose whether to left-align, center-align, or right-align each object in the linear layout.  Note that the above line is precisely the same as

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

Comment: Add android:gravity="center" property in parent layout - which holds your button (child components).

Comment: you also need android.orientation="vertical" plus the layout_gravity in the parent, aka the LInearLayout element....

Answer (score 12):

Add this

```
android:gravity="center"
```

In LinearLayout.

Comment: should be  `android:gravity="center"`

Answer (score 10):

If you use `LinearLayout` you can add gravity center:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
            <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
</LinearLayout>`
```

Answer (score 7):

easy with this

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbEndTrip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Gettings" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnFindMe" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity = "center"
        android:background="@drawable/findme">
    </ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

The above code will work.

Answer (score 4):

As per the Android documentation for XML Attributes of [android:layout_gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity), we can do it easily :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnFindMe" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:background="@drawable/findme"></ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_gravity="center" works fine :) thanks !

Answer (score 2):

complete and working sample from my machine...

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="center">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="My Apps!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
     />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SPOTIFY STREAMER"
        android:id="@+id/button_spotify"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SCORES"
        android:id="@+id/button_scores"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="LIBRARY APP"
        android:id="@+id/button_library"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="BUILD IT BIGGER"
        android:id="@+id/button_buildit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="BACON READER"
        android:id="@+id/button_bacon"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="CAPSTONE: MY OWN APP"
        android:id="@+id/button_capstone"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:padding="20dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can only use 'android:layout_below' on siblings of 'RelativeLayout'

Answer (score 2):

**You can do so by using the gravity="center" attribute in the parent class which makes its child position in the center.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
```

Answer (score 1):

just use  ( to make it in the center of your layout)

```
        android:layout_gravity="center"
```

and use

```
         android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"

         android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
```

to change postion

Answer (score 1):

Set to true  `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and  `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` in the Button, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/switch_flashlight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/turn_on_flashlight"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:onClick="action_trn"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You also can Try this Code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2.0"
            android:background="@drawable/anyBackground" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_mail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/yourImage" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" >



<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/yourImage" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is different from the already provided answers?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the width of the LinearLayout to `wrap_content` and use `android:layout_centerInParent`, `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnFindMe" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:background="@drawable/findme"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

**In this case, you also can use a RelativeLayout As a parent of that *ImageButton***

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

**then use the above code in the ImageButton.**

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFindMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/findme" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you try this?

```
  <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout" android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5px"
android:background="#303030"
>
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget42"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="map"
    android:src="@drawable/outbox_pressed"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/location"
    />
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="location"
    android:src="@drawable/inbox_pressed"
    android:background="@null"
    />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:src="@drawable/button_back"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5px"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#252525"
>
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchfield"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/customshape"
    />
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/search_button"
    android:src="@drawable/search_press"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="apikey" />

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

use

> android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Comment: Actually vogon101, this is a valid property in a RelativeLayout. :)
It doesn't answer the question, though, because the user was using a LinearLayout and wanted to center both vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score -7):

It would be easier to use relative layouts, but for linear layouts I usually center by making sure the width matches parent :

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

and then just give margins to right and left accordingly.

```
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
```