# How to bring button to center of the screen in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a single button in `Linear layout` and I want to keep it at the center (horizontally).
I set `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` for `button` and `linear layout` but no luck.

```
 <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:text="Search"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Sorry for such a basic question but as far as I know only `android:gravity` can be used to bring it to center and it didn't work for me.

**Solution:**

Thanks to Sbossb

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Search"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"></Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

~Ajinkya.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a relative layout and set the child to `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`. LinearLayout are a little tricky when it comes to centering check out this article http://sandipchitale.blogspot.com/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html.

Comment: change android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" in the relative layout to android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Answer (score 5):

Try using this layout!

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It wrappes the button with another Linear layout with horizontal orientation. Thus it will span the parent and allows the center gravity to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It should be android:layout_gravity instead of android:gravity.

Comment: Should I use it for both `button` & `linear layout` ?

Comment: android:gravity can be used on the linearlayout and it sets its child views to be centered. android:layout_gravity sets itself to be centered in the parent view.

Comment: set layout_width on the linear/relative layout to be fill_parent and put the layout_gravity back in.

Comment: I think some other code causing this.Will put some chunk from my code in my question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the solution in this question: [Center a button in a Linear layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957831/centre-a-button-in-a-linear-layout)

Basically, instead of LinearLayout, use RelativeLayout.

Comment: @Ajunkya try to set layout_width to "fill_parent".

Comment: @downvoter can you kindly post a comment? This answer or the one in the link might not suit you, but you could point what is wrong.