# How to center the content inside a linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to center an `ImageView` inside a `LinearLayout` horizontally and vertically, but I just can't do it.
The main reason why I'm not using a `RelativeLayout` for that is because I need the `layout_weight` (my `Activity` consists of four columns that should be equally divided, and also responsive to different screen widths, each column having an `ImageView` centered and unstretched).

Here is my xml so far:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_speak"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_speak" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_readtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_readtext" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_config"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_config" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post screen shot as you want and current screenshot

Answer (score 489, accepted):

`android:gravity` handles the alignment of its children,

`android:layout_gravity` handles the alignment of itself within its parent.

So use one of these.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_speak"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_speak" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_readtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_readtext" />
    </LinearLayout>

    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

(Every node except leaf nodes should have `android:gravity="center"`.)

or

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_speak"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_speak" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_readtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_readtext" />
    </LinearLayout>

    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

(Every node except the root node should have `android:layout_gravity="center"`.)

Comment: "android:layout_gravity takes care of itself." would amend to say layout gravity is used by the parent.

Answer (score 50):

`android:layout_gravity` is used for the layout itself

Use `android:gravity="center"` for children of your `LinearLayout`

So your code should be:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
```

Answer (score 13):

I tried solutions mentioned here but It didn't help me. I mind the solution is `layout_width` have to use `wrap_content` as value.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's some sample code. This worked for me.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

So you're designing the Linear Layout to place all its contents (TextView and Button) in its center, and then the TextView and Button are placed relative to the center of the Linear Layout.

Comment: simple. The 'gravity' attribute affects the content of a view. So in this case what's the content of the LinearLayout? A TextView and a Button. In effect you are instructing the Layout Manager to centralise any content of the Linear Layout.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for an answer in java code,

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
// add children
```

Answer (score 3):

`android:gravity` can be used on a Layout to align its children.

`android:layout_gravity` can be used on any view to align itself in its parent.

> NOTE: If self or children is not centering as expected, check if width/height is `match_parent` and change to something else