# How to create a gridview like Foursquare interest selection screen?

Tags: android, user-interface, gridview, foursquare, tag-cloud

I am creating an app which requires the user to **select multiple** interests.
I am trying to create a screen similar to the Foursquare interest selection **similar to a Tag cloud** where multiple buttons can be selected to represent the users interests.

I have tried creating a gridview but I'm not able to achieve the effect of buttons wrapping up to the next line.

Is there a way this can be achieved via a gridview? Is there a library which does this kind of UI?

[image: Foursquare interest selection screenshot]

Comment: Look for `FlowLayout` on GitHub.

Comment: @Vikram this looks like it https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout Could you post this as an answer, so that I may accept it as an Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `FlowLayout` with `gravity="center_horizontal"`. There are several implementations available, a lot of them as library projects on GitHub. Take you pick :)

[ApmeM/android-flowlayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)

[blazsolar/FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout)

[suanmiao/flowlayout](https://github.com/suanmiao/flowlayout)

(descending *s)

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending a few more minutes on this. Much appreciated.

Comment: @manishKungwani, How to use this in Eclipse projects? Is there any eclipse version?

Comment: @user2459623 which specific library are you looking to use? Ideally if the project compiles to a jar, you can import that jar directly OR mod the project to generate a jar.

Comment: Now I'm able to include those in eclipse, and have an issue with filtering through a edittext on top, any idea? because I don't use adapter here.

Answer (score 3):

This repo may will help someone. 
 https://github.com/Cutta/TagView
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hello there is another example using **custom Library** which acts like List [GitHubLibrary TagLayout](https://github.com/hongyangAndroid/FlowLayout)

- **Sample Code**:-

`mFlowLayout.setAdapter(new TagAdapter<String>(mVals)
   {
       @Override
       public View getView(FlowLayout parent, int position, String s)
       {
           TextView tv = (TextView) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tv,
                   mFlowLayout, false);
           tv.setText(s);
           return tv;
       }
   });`

**Using below code you can pre set selection you wanted:**-

```
mAdapter.setSelectedList(1,3,5,7,8,9);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a LinearLayout with gravity="center". If this does not work for you, then perhaps write your own custom layout that does the linear layout, wrapping, and centering.

For the former, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051472/how-to-center-the-content-inside-a-linear-layout) for an example.