# GridView with Different Columns in Each row

Tags: android, gridview, android-studio, android-custom-view

[image]

I want to implement list in **Android**  like this screenshot. 
Me checked gridview , listview, custom views, but sadly  i donot find any useful tutorials to support gridview with each row  cell/column count changes on data size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130795/how-to-create-a-gridview-like-foursquare-interest-selection-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this [library](https://github.com/Cutta/TagView) according to your need. Alternatively you can edit the source code for you requirements.

It is simple android TagView library.

Answer (score 1):

> You can try with FlowLayout, see bellow libraries:

[hongyangAndroid/FlowLayout](https://github.com/hongyangAndroid/FlowLayout)

[blazsolar/FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout)

[suanmiao/flowlayout](https://github.com/suanmiao/flowlayout)

[android-flowlayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)

[Cutta/TagView](https://github.com/Cutta/TagView)

Answer (score 0):

Use recycler view for list i.e. Your rows and populate each row with your data. Just that now you have to also dynamically add views in each row based upon your conditions