# How to place Button in the center of the screen in a LinearLayout?

Tags: android

Here's my xml using a LinearLayout. Both the Toolbar and the Button are at the top of the screen. However I want the Button centrally horizontal and centrally vertical. Also the Button is floated to the left and not in the center.

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorVeryDark"
        android:elevation="4dp"

        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Use layout_gravity = "center" property or you can use layout_gravity:"center_vertical|center_horizontal"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: use a `RelativeLayout` and use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` for the `Button`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="text"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately LinearLayouts are not the best for this. FrameLayout, RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout will give you the flexibility to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

try to use gravity

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/okbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:text="text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="50sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a RelativeLayout then you add the code:

```
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

in your Button XML.

In alternative, you can use the "design" tool of AndroidStudio for layouts: you can add a button and then drag wherever you want in the preview.

However, there are tons of post like this: next time try to search better :D

Comment: Just tried that, the button is now in the top left corner (behind the Toolbar). Any idea?

Comment: Can i see your XML? Just to check if everything is all right.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines in you Button

```
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

refer this image for proper understanding of use of gravity

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use this line of code in your button xml design-

```
android:gravity="center"
```

For more ideas you can check this link-
[Center a button in a Linear layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957831/center-a-button-in-a-linear-layout)